# Yum Check Available Package Updates

Tags: rhel, yum

Red Hat [docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html#sec-Checking_For_Updates) say:

> To see which installed packages on your system have updates available,
>   use the following command:

`yum check-update`

What command must I run to view all `available` versions for a package installed on my system?

Example: `yum check-update` tells me `java6` update `#43` is available, but what if I want update `#40`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This command won't focus specifically on one package, but by using a regex to do the matching you can still see what's available:

```
$ yum list available java\*
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat.i386                                                   1.4.2.0-40jpp.115                                                      installed
java-1.6.0-openjdk.i386                                                      1:1.6.0.0-1.36.1.11.9.el5_9                                            installed
Available Packages
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-devel.i386                                             1.4.2.0-40jpp.115                                                      base     
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-javadoc.i386                                           1.4.2.0-40jpp.115                                                      base     
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-src.i386                                               1.4.2.0-40jpp.115                                                      base     
java-1.6.0-openjdk.i386                                                      1:1.6.0.0-1.40.1.11.11.el5_9                                           updates  
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.i386                                                 1:1.6.0.0-1.40.1.11.11.el5_9
```

You can make it "smarter" by filtering the output using `grep`.

Comment: Then I can run `yum update <package-name>` provided the package, to which I'm trying to upgrade, is, in fact, a higher version of my currently installed package?

Comment: That would be correct. You can update to the next version from what you currently have installed.

Comment: Note that the official repositories _very_ rarely carry more than one version of a package, old packages are obsoleted for a reason.

Comment: You want to use --show-duplicates to see all the versions, but as vonbrand said if you are using CentOS/Fedora you only get the latest anyway (If you pay for actual RHEL, you'll get a lot of choice and may want to look at the upgrade-to command as well).

Answer (score 13):

To see currently installed package version + check what is the latest available version, use `--showduplicates list <package name>`, for example:

```
$ sudo yum --showduplicates list 'tar.*'

Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos
Installed Packages
tar.x86_64   2:1.26-32.el7    installed              
Available Packages
tar.x86_64   2:1.26-29.el7    rhelosp-rhel-7.4-server
tar.x86_64   2:1.26-31.el7    rhelosp-rhel-7.4-server
tar.x86_64   2:1.26-32.el7    rhelosp-rhel-7.4-server
```

Comment: `--showduplicates` is exactly what I was looking for.